# Why are the two answers different?

Tags: regression

I found exponential regression on Desmos for a few values:

[image]

I want to find the X value when Y is 40,000. So, when zooming in on 40,000, I see that X is around 160. But, when putting the equation:

```
y=7.4927(1.0695)^x
```

in Wolfram Alpha, I get `x = 127.735`. Why are the two answers different?

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at the $y$ value 400,000, not 40,000!

If you solve $7.4927 (1.0695)^x = 400,000$ numerically, you should get $127.735$, just like the answer from Wolfram Alpha.

[image]

Comment: I came to the same conclusion: the 400k vs 40 issue. Looks like an extra zero typo somewhere by the OP.

Comment: Oh my gosh. Is there anyway to actually pinpoint the dot at Y = 40,000 and see the X value there? I can never see that X value properly, as when I place the dot on the line `Y=40,000` it shows me coordinates for `Y=40,001`. Please explain how to get the coordinates. I will accept your answer once I confirm by pinpointing the 40,000 on the graph, but I'm unable to do that.  I have liked your post 400,000 times! :)

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Unfortunately, I don't think Desmos supports solving for $x$ given $y$. But there is a way around this. You could graph $y=40,000$. and find the intersection point between this line and your regression line! I hope this helps!

Comment: @GaussTheBauss Hey, that helps a lot. But, how do I graph `y = 40,000`? Feel free to post an answer! Thanks

Comment: @RuchirBaronia just type $y=40000$ on the right.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I have added a picture. It helps to change the range of $x$ and $y$ to find the intersection point.